# Document not able to fetch from mongodb through golang because of date format issue. Using mgm package for it

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, go-fiber

In our document collection, appnt_date is in date type format and to fetch the documents on the basis of the given appnt_date, we need to provide the query in mongo db compass as:

```
{
  "appnt_date": {
    "$eq": ISODate("2024-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
}

The above query is fetching the results correctly in Mongo db compass.
```

Now in order to fetch the document from golang code on the basis of the given appnt_date which is in time.Time type in golang, I am not able to fetch document from mongo on the basis of date.

Need help on this. I tried various methods like:

1)

```
targetDate := time.Date(2024, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
   targetDateTime := primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(targetDate)
filter := bson.M{
            "appnt_date":  targetDateTime}
```

2. targetDate := time.Date(2024, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

   formattedDate := targetDate.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z")

   filter := bson.M{
   "appnt_date":  formattedDate}

But none of them worked.
appnt_date in mongo is in the format: `appnt_date: 2024-01-25T00:00:00.000+00:00`

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, pleaese mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.Parse()` to convert a string date to golang's `time.Time`. Example:

```
// using RFC3339 time layout
targetDateTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2024-01-25T00:00:00.000+00:00")
if err != nil {
  ... handle error
}

...

filter := bson.M{"appnt_date":  targetDateTime}
```